# How to build an iterator for Hash Table?

Tags: python, hash

I have a hash table class and after items are added to the hash table, i want to iterate over the hash table to perform counting and etc and I'm wondering how would it be done?

I'm assuming that the iterator class for hash tables are far more simpler than the ones for Linked List since it utilises arrays rather than nodes.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
class HashIterator:
   def __init__(self, first):
       self.current = first

   def __next__(self):
       item = self.current.item
       self.current = self.current.next
       return item

   def __iter__(self):
       return self
```

but I'm quite lost as I'm more used to creating iterators for linked list and such but not hash tables that is array based.

Comment: Can you give a sketch of your hash table class?

Comment: There must be a point, where `__next__` starts to raise `StopIteration`.